# Ruby do a git diff

Tags: ruby, git, github, rubygems

I'm very new to Ruby and pretty much never written using it.
However I'm trying to write a server shakeout script using Ruby. It's pretty much the only option available to me.

What I want to do is a git diff of a file on a remote repository and local file. If they're the same return true, otherwise return false.

```
String localFile = "file.txt"
String remoteRepo = "git@github.com:achinthaguansekara/server_spec.git"

git diff between localFile and file on remoteRepo

if same
    return true
else
    return false
```

Is there a way to do this using Ruby?

Please note file.txt is a example. What I actually want to check is the httpd.conf file on my apache installation. This file is stored on our central git server for versioning and any changes are made to this file. This file then gets deployed to the web server running apache via Puppet and Puppet reloads the apache configuration.

What I want to do is to make sure, httpd.conf version on the web server is the same as what's on git server.

My limitation is, I can only use Ruby to do this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cool thing about Ruby is that if there is a common problem, then there's probably [already a gem built addressing it](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git).

In this case, the `ruby-git` gem seems to provide some diff functionality that you'd like. I'd check out the `status` piece of the gem for a starting point.

Comment: This is more of a comment. What is the syntax to diff two different branches?

Answer (score 0):

I would forget the single file and trying to only do one operation and just use git as normal:

1. clone the repository
2. make your changes locally

Now you can compare the local file with either of the following (assuming your remote is called origin)

```
git diff origin # can be done offline
```

or, to compare with the latest remote version:

```
git fetch
git diff origin
```

you can `git diff origin file.txt` to be more specific, e.g. if you have other local file changes.